# Instance method xyz not found (return type defaults to id)?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I am facing issue for a method, which I have using for other NSString and working fine.

See this image.

[image]

Here html is NSString, I have used it in other project, like a clone of this, its working fine there, even I wrote like this, working fine in that project,

```
html = [html stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText];
```

but here in this method , both the ways giving this warning. 
What that mean and how can I solve it
?

Comment: It sounds as if that other project had a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) declaring that method

Comment: Import the category that has that method declared in.

Comment: SOlved. it was not imported, but I am amazed, why it didn't give me error, why warning?

Comment: Just remember in iOS 6 (XCode 4.6), those library file is not working

Answer (score 0):

If `html`is typed as an `id`, but you know that it's in fact an `NSString`, try casting it to `NSString`and call your selector from there ([id type to NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806474/id-type-to-nsstring)).

That said, the reported error often occurs when your method is not declared in your header file (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13154244/865688). Did you forget to `#import`?

Answer (score 0):

"stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText" is not a standard method defined in the NSString class. It is s commonly used category defined in the [MWFeedParser](https://github.com/renegade78/MWFeedParser/) project.

Make sure you have imported the category using the right syntax. Refer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html Search for text "import the category header file" read around that area if not the whole chapter.